# delete link not deleting any record in mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to add a delete link to every row of record displayed on my page. I have managed to that so far but cannot figure out how to make the link work so that when a delete link is clicked, only that row of data will be removed from the database. I am farly new to php/mysql so pardon my questions. I have the following code so far..

```
<?php
require("common.php");

if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
{ 
header("Location: index.php"); 

die("Redirecting to index.php");
}

$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM compliance_requirement");
$result->execute();

?>


<div class="compTable">
<table >
<tr>
<th>Compliance Name</th><th>Compliance Goal</th><th>Compliance Description</th>  <th>Options</th>
</tr>

<?php while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>
<tr>

<td style='width: 200px;'><?php echo $row['ComplianceName']; ?></td>
<td style='width: 150px;'><?php echo $row['ComplianceGoal']; ?></td>
<td style='width: 400px;'><?php echo $row['ComplianceDescription']; ?></td>

<td style ='width: 250px;' ><?php echo '<a href="delete.php?action=delete&id=delete'.$row['ComplianceName'].'">Delete</a>';?>   

</td>
</tr>
<?php } 
?> 
</table>
</div>
```

.. and then in my delete.php file, I have the following code:

```
<?php
require ('common.php');

if( isset($_GET['delete']) )
{
$id = $_GET['delete'];
$sql= $db->prepare("DELETE FROM compliance_requirement WHERE ComplianceName='$id'");
$sql->execute();
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=compliance.php'>";
}
?>
```

When the delete link is clicked, it just comes up with a blank screen. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Have you verified error reporting is on?

Comment: Please look at SQL injection and why the way you're doing this is very dangerous.

Comment: You're looking to see if `$_GET['del']` is set. But that's not the parameter that your HTML is passing. Your code will only do something if that parameter is set - if it's missing, no code will be executed.

Comment: Changed '$id' to a place holder (?) then pass $id through execute -> execute(array($id)); otherwise could be used for sql injection

Comment: Won't fix your problem at hand, but you need to fix these `<div class="compTable"` and `<table >` --- that alone will play some nasty tricks. **Do:** `<div class="compTable">` and `<table>`

Comment: @saint FYI, In `delete.php` your not using prepared query's correctly, sql injection is still possible

Comment: @JohnConde yes I do have error reporting on now but making no real difference. I have edited the code a bit more to reflect your suggestions. please take a a look. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **`a href`** tag should be [*Missed quotes*]

```
<?php echo '<a href="delete.php?action=delete&id='.$row['ComplianceName'].'">Delete</a>';?>  
<?php echo '<a href="delete.php?edit='.$row['ComplianceID'].'">Edit</a>';?> 
<?php echo '<a href="delete.php?invite='.$row['id'].'">Invite Obstacle</a>';?>
```

Comment: Also note the " double quotes on the statement.  echo "value: $foo" vs echo 'value: $foo';  Only the first one is valid.  @saint familiar with tools like [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/)?

Comment: This wouldn't still work. Either use curly braces, like `&id={$row['ComplianceName']}"` or remove the single-quotes:  `&id=$row[ComplianceName]"`. :)

Comment: thanks for the comment. I made the suggested changes but still comes up with the blank page and message: http://localhost/delete.php?action=delete&id={$row[ComplianceName]. in the local host. could it be that its not connecting to my delete.php at all?? thanks

Comment: @ficuscr.. no i haven't used firebug before. just googled it now. somethig you would recommend??

Comment: @saint Yes!  That or developer tools for Chrome (F12).  Once you start using it you'll wonder how you ever lived without it.  Here for example, easier to inspect the id/name tags you generated than looking through page source.  Also with things like Xhr posts much easier to inspect.  Many useful features really.

Comment: @ficuscr thanks. I will certainly check it out after this project as it might take time getting used to.. running behind schedule on this at the moment so need to figure out how to fix these errors first!

Answer (score 1):

I find when constructing a dynamic link it is best to create the url (You can echo it  during testing)first. This avoids the confusion of quotes. The url is then easy to use in link.

```
<?php 
   while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
     $url = "delete.php?action=delete&id=".$row['ComplianceName'];
     //echo $url;
?>
<tr>
  <td style='width: 200px;'><?php echo $row['ComplianceName']; ?></td>
  <td style='width: 150px;'><?php echo $row['ComplianceGoal']; ?></td>
  <td style='width: 400px;'><?php echo $row['ComplianceDescription']; ?></td>
  <td style ='width: 250px;' ><?php echo '<a href ='.$url.'>' ?> Delete </a>
```

Example of link

```
<td style ='width: 250px;' ><a href =delete.php?action=delete&id=name1> Delete </a>
```

Comment: thanks for the help. do you have any idea how i can twick the delete.php code so it actually deletes and updates the selected row?