# Echo delete link into php

Tags: php

I have a question regarding a delete function into php.
Consindiring PHP I'm a real noob in this.

I want to make a delete link into a php loop.

This is my home.php:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='info-item'>".$row["userID"]."</td>";
    echo "<td class='info-item'>".$row["userName"]." </td>";
    echo "<td class='info-item'>".$row["userLast"]."</td>";
    echo "<td class='info-item'>".$row["userDegree"]."</td>";
    echo "<td class='info-item'>".$row["userOrganization"]."</td>";
    echo "<td class='info-item'>".$row["userIndustry"]."</td>";
    echo "<td class='info-item'>".$row["userAddress-1"]."</td>";
    echo "<td class='info-item'>".$row["userAddress-1"]."</td>";
    echo "<td class='info-item'><a href='$delete'>Link</a></td>";
}
```

This line:

```
echo "<td class='info-item'><a href='$delete'>Link</a></td>";
```

is not working.

for `$delete` I use this on top of my script:

```
$delete = "delete.php";
```

It goes to delete.php that looks like this.

```
ob_start();
include("dbconfig.php");
if(isset($_GET['userID'])!="") {
    $delete=$_GET['userID'];
    $delete=mysql_query("DELETE FROM tbl_users WHERE userID='$delete'");
    if($delete)
        header("Location:index.php");
    else
        echo mysql_error();
}
ob_end_flush();
```

But nothing appears to happen regarding the delete of a certain id that I clicked.

Please help.

Comment: What is the HTML output of this code? It will give you a table view. Can you show the HTML output?

Comment: Well, you don't seem to be setting the ID in the `$delete` variable or passing it to the link? you need to do something like `$delete = 'delete.php?userID=' . $userID;`

Comment: possible duplicates of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729887/delete-link-not-deleting-any-record-in-mysql-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your delete is not working because it is redundant and static. You should make it Dynamic by (at least) appending the user ID to the `delete.php`. This `id` would then be used to determine which record to delete...

```
    <?php
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            // GENERATE AN ID BASED URL FOR THE DELETE
            // THIS WOULD READ SOMETHING LIKE: "delete?id=1" 
            // AND THE ID WOULD BE UNIQUE ACROSS EACH ROW....
            // YOU CAN THEN USE THE ID ($_GET['userID'] TO DETERMINE WHICH USER
            // ADD userId WHICH RECORD YOU HAVE TO DELETE....
            $delete = "delete.php?userID="  . $row["userID"];
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td class='info-item'>"   . $row["userID"]            . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='info-item'>"   . $row["userName"]          . " </td>";
            echo "<td class='info-item'>"   . $row["userLast"]          . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='info-item'>"   . $row["userDegree"]        . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='info-item'>"   . $row["userOrganization"]  . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='info-item'>"   . $row["userIndustry"]      . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='info-item'>"   . $row["userAddress-1"]     . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='info-item'>"   . $row["userAddress-1"]     . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='info-item'><a href='{$delete}' >Delete User</a></td>";
        }
```

**PHP:**

```
    <?php

        // USING PDO...
        //DATABASE CONNECTION CONFIGURATION:
        defined("HOST")         or define("HOST",           "localhost");
        defined("DBASE")        or define("DBASE",          "yourDB");
        defined("USER")         or define("USER",           "root");
        defined("PASS")         or define("PASS",           "root");

        ob_start();
        if(isset($_GET['userID'])!="") {
            $userID         = $_GET['userID'];
            try {
                $dbh        = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='. DBASE,USER,PASS);
                $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                $query      = "DELETE FROM `tbl_users` WHERE userID='{$userID}'";
                $stmt       = $dbh->prepare($query);
                $deleteOK   = $stmt->execute();

                if ($deleteOK) {
                    header("Location:index.php");
                }

            }catch(PDOException $e){
                throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: Mate why not use the correct syntax? You edited thrice. **1.** There's no `=` sign. **2.** The `id` should be `userID`.

Comment: It still is not deleting it from the database.

Comment: @Dionoh        The Problem is with the $_GET['userID'] Variable. Before, it was $_GET['userId']. Right now, it is changed.... You may want to try it one more time if you still wish to...

Comment: @Poiz Now it says : No database selected

Comment: @Poiz This is for the delete.php?

Comment: @Dionoh Yes, it is.... but make sure you change your Database Connection Information like USER, PASS, HOST, DBASE,

Comment: @poiz Now i get this message:  `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.com\delete.php:26 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.com\delete.php on line 26`

Comment: @Poiz it is coming but still getting the fatal error:  `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'yourdb'' in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.com\delete.php:26 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.com\delete.php on line 26`

Comment: @Poiz i will do that but i want to learn. What did you specifically change to the SQL?

Comment: @Dionoh   Earlier, the SQL was `DELETE FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:UID"`  but then I changed it to a normal SQL `DELETE FROM tbl_users WHERE userID='{$userID}'"`

Comment: @Poiz So this way it get's it straight away from the database userID?

Answer (score 0):

You should include the user ID in the link:

```
echo "<td class='info-item'><a href='$delete?userID={$row["userID"]}'>Link</a></td>";
```

Besides, your code is prone to SQL injection and uses the mysql_* functions which will not be supported any more in the future. Replace them with functions from the mysqli or PDO classes.

Answer (score 0):

When you are sending the control to another page, the `$delete` variable will not be passed on. So it is always better to use a query string. My best solution will be:

- Get the ID from the database.
- Append the ID to the link.
- Use the `$_GET` to get the query string of record.

`home.php` code:

```
echo "<td class='info-item'><a href='{$delete}?userID=".$row["userID"]."'>Link</a></td>";
```

Now in the main `delete.php`:

```
$delete = $_GET["userID"];
```

> **Note:** Your code has a lot of vulnerabilities. Do not use `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated.

Comment: I get this on my screen `No database selected`

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending `userID` with your url, change here.

```
echo "<td class='info-item'><a href='$delete?userID=".$row["userID"]."'>Link</a></td>";
```

Also use exit after `header` here

```
header("Location:index.php");
exit;
```